# What does "only failed to notify" status means?

Tags: msdtc

I'm using MS DTC as a Transaction Manager for my application. Looking at the transaction list, there are *many* with the status

> Only failed to notify

As you can see from the image below. What does it means?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when Prepare-phase has finished and all Resource Managers voted to commit distributed transaction, however during Commit-phase MSDTC was not able to notify at least one of RM to perform commit operation.